# Wacom Pressure in Photoshop CS5 Using Wine

Tags: wine, wacom, photoshop

*I'm taking a shot in the dark hoping someone here has figured this out, because they haven't figured it out at winehq, which I know is the more appropriate forum to ask.  But,no one knows (that I know of), so here goes:*

Do you know how to get the *wacom pen pressure* to work in Adobe Photoshop CS5 using wacom tablet?  It works fine in MyPaint, Gimp, Pencil etc.  So I know this is a wine issue with the wacom pressure settings.

I can provide any information you feel is helpful in solving this, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

the answer isn't easy, you need to develop or pay someone to develop on your behalf a wine driver which can use pressure information from xinput devices and deliver them to windows programs in the way they expect.

This project might take a lot of time or a lot of money to get written. But I know that it has not yet been written and needs artists to step up to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I am finding that running Utopic Unicorn with a cracked version of Wine which has been optimized for Ubuntu is working well and every now and then (if I leave pen pressure setting on) I find it registers the pen pressure and draws a thin line. I have no idea what is doing this. I installed it with POL and have it using Opengl only, alongside Wine version 1.7.2.

I originally had a problem with the brush not working at all. If I knew a way to identify what is happening when Photoshop registers the pen pressure I'm sure a solution could be found.