# Photshop digital painting on wine

Tags: wacom, photoshop

I have Ubuntu 13.04, and downloaded the latest version of wine, installed Photoshop CS6 and CS5 and found that in both digital painting is impossible..

Is there a good novice guide to download Photoshop and Wacom drivers.. All I could find are incredible complicated guides

Oh and does anybody have any experience with this..

Will it be better for me just to have dual boot?

Comment: Another option is to use the program virtualbox and install windows or mac through that. It's very easy to do and there are a lot of step by step instructions for setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

As you [seem not to be able to use your Wacom tablet through Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219336/wacom-pressure-in-photoshop-cs5-using-wine) you have three options:

- switch to a native Ubuntu application (that would likely be Gimp) which allows drawing with a pressure sensitive device (see e.g. [How to set pressure sensitivity in GIMP to control line thickness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48771/how-to-set-pressure-sensitivity-in-gimp-to-control-line-thickness)).
- Install and run Photoshop on Windows with an USB enabled virtual machine (this would be at the cost of performance).
- Dual boot for best performance when running Photoshop on Windows or Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to install VirtualBox 
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
then install win-doze inside VirtualBox, (install CS5/6 in win-doze). This will eliminate your dual-boot problem, and allow you to run both win-doze and Ubuntu at the same time!